# If $a\in R$ and the equation $-3(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)^2+2(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)+a^2=0$ has no integral solution,then all possible values of $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $a\in R$ and the equation $-3(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)^2+2(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)+a^2=0$ has no integral solution, then all possible values of $a$ lie in the interval 
$(A)(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$
$(B)(1,2)$
 
$(C)(-2,-1)$
$(D)(-\infty,-2)\cup(2,\infty)$

---

My try:
Let $x-\lfloor x \rfloor  = \{x\}= t$, where $ 0 \leq \{x\}<1\Rightarrow 0\leq t<1$. Then

$$\Rightarrow -3t^2+2t+a^2 = 0\Rightarrow 3t^2-2t-a^2 = 0$$

$$\displaystyle \Rightarrow t = \frac{2\pm \sqrt{4+12a^2}}{6} = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{1+3a^2}}{3}$$
I do not know how to solve further.

Comment: Integral solution means $t=0$. There is one only if $a=0$, so possible values of $a$ are $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Are you sure there are no more restrictions (like $-3y^2+2y+a^2$ having a solution)?

Comment: See also: [If $ -3\left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor \right)^2+2(x-\lfloor x \rfloor )+a^2=0$.has no integral solution, then $a$ is](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/802974)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT (ELABORATION)**

There is probably a typo here; it should say real solutions.

Assume it has solutions. 
$$0\leq t<1,  t=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1+3a^2}}{3} \Leftrightarrow 1 \le \sqrt{1+3a^2} < 2 $$
From the fact that $1-\sqrt{1+3a^2}<0$ if $a \neq 0$. From here, we square both sides to get $$0 \le a^2 \le 1$$
This implies $-1 \le a \le 1$.

Comment: Yes i am getting answer with $1\leq\sqrt{1+3a^2}<2$ but i do not understand how you got this one.@MXYMXY

Comment: @Brahmagupta The smaller value  among $\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1+3a^2}}{3}$ would be $\frac{1-\sqrt{1+3a^2}}{3}$, the larger value would be $\frac{1+ \sqrt{1+3a^2}}{3}$ The minimum value would be less or equal to $0$, and the maximum value would be less than $1$

Answer (score 3):

**First**, let us see for which values of $a$ there *will be* solutions:

---

Since $\,0\leq t = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor<1\,$ we have

\begin{align}
t &= \dfrac{1\pm \sqrt{1+3a^2}}{3}  \in \left[0,1\right) 
&\implies&& 0\le1\pm\sqrt{1+3a^2} < 3
\\
&\big(\text{subtract } 1 \text{ from each inequality}\big)
&\implies&& -1\le\pm\sqrt{1+3a^2} < 2
\end{align}
Now consider two cases separately:

1. $\,-1\le + \sqrt{1+3a^2} < 2\,$
   \begin{align}
   &-1\le \sqrt{1+3a^2} < 2&\implies&& 0\le\sqrt{1+3a^2} < 2
   \\
   &\big(\text{square both sides of each inequality}\big)
   &\implies&& 0\leq 1+3a^2 <4
   \\
   &\big(\text{subtract } 1\big)
   &\implies&& 0\leq 3a^2<3
   \\
   &\big(\text{divide by } 3\big)
   &\implies&& 0\leq a^2 < 1
   \\
   &&\implies&& \bbox[1ex, border:solid 1.5pt #e10000]{a\in\left(-1,1\right)}
   \end{align}
2. $\,-1\le - \sqrt{1+3a^2} < 2\,$
   \begin{align}
   &-1\le- \sqrt{1+3a^2} < 2&\implies&&  0 < \sqrt{1+3a^2} \leq 1
   \\
   &\big(\text{square both sides of each inequality}\big)
   &\implies&& 0\lt 1+3a^2 \leq 1
   \\
   &\big(\text{subtract } 1 \text{ again}\big)
   &\implies&& -1\lt 3a^2 \leq 0
   \\
   &&\implies&& \bbox[1ex, border:solid 1.5pt #e10000]{a = 0}
   \end{align}

---

**Second**, find which values of $a$ correspond to the *integral* solution of the equation. The answer will be complement to the set of these values in $\mathbb R$.